# Symfony 2: CRUD-Controller - how?

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, crud

I'm writing a Controller to handle the basic CRUD-functionality and would like to know, if I got it right.

Symfony has a lot of great functionality itself and **I wonder, if I'm reinventing the wheel** in this case. I've about 20 classes that will be extended by the **CRUDController** and I'd like to use best-practices, as early as possible.

Thanks in advance!

**CRUDController.php**

```
namespace myApp\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CRUDController extends Controller {

    protected $repo;
    protected $em = 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager';
    protected $templatePath;
    protected $itemsAlias = 'items';
    protected $itemAlias = 'item';
    protected $listingTemplate = 'list';
    protected $saveTemplate = 'save';
    protected $templateFileExtension = '.html.twig';   
    protected $entity;
    protected $formType; 
    protected $formMethod = 'POST';
    protected $indexRoute;
    protected $addSuccessMessage = 'Added.';
    protected $addErrorMessage = 'Not added';
    protected $editSuccessMessage = 'Edited.';
    protected $editErrorMessage = 'Not Edited.';

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render($this->templatePath . $this->listingTemplate . $this->templateFileExtension, array(
            $this->itemsAlias => $this->get($this->repo)->findAll()
        ));
    }

    public function addAction(Request $request) {
        return $this->save($request);
    }

    public function editAction($id, Request $request) {
        return $this->save($request, $id);
    }

    protected function save(Request $request, $id = null) {

        if (is_null($id)) {
            $item = new $this->entity();
        } else {
            $item = $this->get($this->repo)->find($id);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new $this->formType(), $item);
        if ($request->isMethod($this->formMethod)) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->get($this->em);
                $em->persist($item);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'success',
                    is_null($id) ? $this->addSuccessMessage : $this->editSuccessMessage
                );
            } else {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'error',
                    is_null($id) ? $this->addErrorMessage : $this->editErrorMessage
                );
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($this->indexRoute));
        }

        return $this->render($this->templatePath . $this->saveTemplate . $this->templateFileExtension, array(
             'form' => $form->createView(),
             $this->itemAlias => $item
        ));
    }
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
namespace myApp\MyBundle\Controller;
use myApp\MyBundle\CRUDController;

class MyController extends CRUDController {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->repo         = 'myapp.service.repository.item';
        $this->templatePath = '@myapp/items/';
        $this->itemsAlias   = 'myItems';
        $this->itemAlias    = 'myItem';
        $this->entity       = 'myApp\myBundle\Entity\Item';
        $this->formType     = 'myApp\myBundle\Form\Type\ItemType';
        $this->indexRoute   = 'items_index';
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of rolling your own, consider experimenting with one of the many crud bundles out there.  For example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experience - "Universal Crud Controller" is helpfull only when project is starting. During development a lot of entities requires custom modifications.
Second thing about your idea: in save method, you should have IF around `$em->persist($item);` because existing entities cannot be persisted again.
Last thing: During development (and using this code) you should think about "owning side" of relations, because Doctrine can handle changes on owning side only. It produces problem like this:
Product has many Categories - relation bidirectional. Join table is in product annotation. You can add Category to Product and save it successfully. But adding Product To Category wont save changes to database (of course you can handle it manually during save:]).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd use the "Universal Crud Controller" just for simple CRUD-functionality. If any method needs different functionality, I'd overwrite it.